# Kraken API - ColdFusion

Tags: api, coldfusion, sha256, sha512, kraken.com

Trying to tackle the Kraken API. Using ColdFusion 2016.
I have a few tries in here, but can't seem to quite get it.
So testing message, message2, message3 attempts.

https://docs.kraken.com/rest/#section/Authentication/Headers-and-Signature

HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key

EXPECTED RESULT:

`4/dpxb3iT4tp/ZCVEwSnEsLxx0bqyhLpdfOpc6fn7OR8+UClSV5n9E6aSS8MPtnRfp32bAb0nmbRn6H8ndwLUQ==`

```
<cfset _key = "APIKEY">
<cfset _s = "kQH5HW/8p1uGOVjbgWA7FunAmGO8lsSUXNsu3eow76sz84Q18fWxnyRzBHCd3pd5nE9qa99HAZtuZuj6F">
<cfset nonce = "1616492376594">
<cfset payload = "nonce=1616492376594&ordertype=limit&pair=XBTUSD&price=37500&type=buy&volume=1.25">
<cfset URIPath = "/0/private/AddOrder">

<cfscript>

    apiKey = "#_key#";
    apiSecret = "#_s#";
    theKeyBytes = charsetDecode(#_s#, "UTF-8");
    _Secret64 = toBase64(#_s#);

    // get_kraken_signature(urlpath, data, secret):

    h = '#uripath#' & #payload#;
    _hash = hmac(h, theKeyBytes, "HMACSHA256");


    //HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key

    //SHA256(nonce + POST data))
    _256 = hmac(payload, "HMACSHA256");
    _sign = hmac(payload, theKeyBytes, "HMACSHA256");

    // HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data))
    message = '#uripath#' & #_256#;
    message2 = '#uripath#' & #_256# & #_Secret64#;
    message3 = '#uripath#' & #_sign# & #_Secret64#;

    _512 = hmac(#message#, "HMACSHA512");
    _512_2 = hmac(#message2#, "HMACSHA512");
    _512_3 = hmac(#message3#, "HMACSHA512");

    _512_H = hmac(#_hash#, "HMACSHA512");
    S_H = hmac(#_512_h#, #_s#, "HmacSHA512");
    H64 = toBase64(binaryDecode(#s_h#, "hex"));


    // base64 decoded secret API key
    _64 = toBase64(#_512#);

    S_Hex = hmac(#_512#, #_s#, "HmacSHA512");
    Hex64 = toBase64(binaryDecode(#s_hex#, "hex"));

    S_Hex2 = hmac(#_512_2#, #_s#, "HmacSHA512");
    Hex642 = toBase64(binaryDecode(#s_hex2#, "hex"));

    S_Hex3 = hmac(#_512_3#, #_s#, "HmacSHA512");
    Hex643 = toBase64(binaryDecode(#s_hex3#, "hex"));

</cfscript>
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

`4/dpxb3iT4tp/ZCVEwSnEsLxx0bqyhLpdfOpc6fn7OR8+UClSV5n9E6aSS8MPtnRfp32bAb0nmbRn6H8ndwLUQ==`

Hex64 Gets:
`w1PXl7IDLs1Pri1Vf++UcLFWIFedkxgpceFVkVFbxt7wvjj/Q0wtwwLSMJxV7bMOdFi+BEN3lHuX+CWRx2SxAQ==`

Hex642 Gets:
`Zxd+96KuI3wSQJ/b0l79djB1M7FMsczoWOfs9Ha5YWIC6sc6uryEGn4MgkcHnF/ndsxDQ2y/jSHl0RxTIuc7PA==`

Hex643 Gets:
`5KCKhgRGexBPF7SgnSB5G0m3bu+2ecf4fAOndDG0pvYLh0PeWC1nWodi5szigcGU4TyLLb80jPNAR7OmK0t0Sw==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking this question as an exercise, I've managed to translate the python function from KrakenAPI docs to CFML script. That function should help you and others with a practical solution. Also publishing it here for my own documentation:

```
<cfscript>

    public string function getKrakenSignature( urlpath, postdata, nonce, secretAsBase64) localmode=true {

        // assign arguments to local variables
        urlpath= arguments.urlpath;
        nonce= arguments.nonce;
        postdata = arguments.postdata;
        secretAsBase64= arguments.secretAsBase64;

        // convert urlpath to a binary Hex representation 
        urlpathBinary= toBinary( toBase64( urlpath ));
        urlpathBinaryAsHex= BinaryEncode( urlpathBinary, "HEX");


        // convert secret to binary
        secretBinary= ToBinary(  arguments.secretAsBase64 );

        // concatenate nonce and postdata
        noncePostdata = nonce & postdata; 

        //get binary digest as Hex representation
        noncePostdataDigestBinaryAsHex= hash( noncePostdata, "SHA-256" );


        // concatenate urlPath binary (hex) and oncePostdataDigest binary (hex) 
        messageBinaryAsHex= urlpathBinaryAsHex & noncePostdataDigestBinaryAsHex;

        // convert message hex representation to binary
        messageBinary= BinaryDecode( messageBinaryAsHex, "HEX");

        // sign the message with hmac function
        messageHmacDigestBinaryAsHex = hmac( messageBinary, secretBinary, "HMACSHA512");
        messageHmacDigestBinary=BinaryDecode( messageHmacDigestBinaryAsHex, "HEX");

        return binaryEncode( messageHmacDigestBinary, "base64" );

    }

encodedPayLoad="nonce=1616492376594&ordertype=limit&pair=XBTUSD&price=37500&type=buy&volume=1.25";
nonce="1616492376594";
api_sec = "kQH5HW/8p1uGOVjbgWA7FunAmGO8lsSUXNsu3eow76sz84Q18fWxnyRzBHCd3pd5nE9qa99HAZtuZuj6F1huXg==";
urlpath="/0/private/AddOrder";
signature = getKrakenSignature( urlpath, encodedPayLoad, nonce, api_sec);
writeoutput( signature );

</cfscript>
```

Find a gist here at [tryCf.com](https://trycf.com/gist/6c68db524042a0c5535ab6b687599b9c/lucee5?theme=monokai)

Answer (score 0):

Yes answer above works.
Arrrgh - I had the wrong Secret Key - Cut Paste issue. I only figured it out when reversing the secretkey - that script below as well

kQH5HW/8p1uGOVjbgWA7FunAmGO8lsSUXNsu3eow76sz84Q18fWxnyRzBHCd3pd5nE9qa99HAZtuZuj6F

vs

kQH5HW/8p1uGOVjbgWA7FunAmGO8lsSUXNsu3eow76sz84Q18fWxnyRzBHCd3pd5nE9qa99HAZtuZuj6F1huXg==

Credit AndreasRu above for that answer and method.

I am posting another method below.  I have used this one for most of the Crypto API's.

HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key

```
    <cfset _key = "APIKEY">
    <cfset _s = "kQH5HW/8p1uGOVjbgWA7FunAmGO8lsSUXNsu3eow76sz84Q18fWxnyRzBHCd3pd5nE9qa99HAZtuZuj6F1huXg==">
    <cfset nonce = "1616492376594">
    <cfset payload = "nonce=1616492376594&ordertype=limit&pair=XBTUSD&price=37500&type=buy&volume=1.25">
    <cfset URIPath = "/0/private/AddOrder">

    <cfscript>

    // URIPATH to a binary Hex
    BURL64 = toBinary(toBase64(#URIPath#));
    URLHEX = BinaryEncode(BURL64,"HEX");

    // Secret to binary
    SB = ToBinary(#_s#);

    // SHA256(nonce + POST data)
    SHA256_Post = '#nonce#' & #payload#;
    SHA_256 = hash(#SHA256_Post#, "SHA-256", "UTF-8");

    // BUILD SHA-512
    URI256POST = '#urlhex#' & #SHA_256#;

    // convert SHA512 buid to message hex
    MESSAGEHEX = BinaryDecode(URI256POST,"HEX");

    // messageHex to HMAC SHA-512
    M512 = hmac(#MESSAGEHEX#, #SB#, "HMACSHA512");
    M512HEX = BinaryDecode(M512,"HEX");

    // Final Signature
    SignFinal = toBase64(M512HEX);

    </cfscript>

    <cfoutput>

    EXPECTED RESULT:
    4/dpxb3iT4tp/ZCVEwSnEsLxx0bqyhLpdfOpc6fn7OR8+UClSV5n9E6aSS8MPtnRfp32bAb0nmbRn6H8ndwLUQ==

    #signfinal#

    </cfoutput>
```

Figuring out secret code below. Not needed for Kraken API-Sign

```
    <cfscript>

    hexEncoded = binaryEncode(secretBinary, "hex");
    base64Encoded = binaryEncode(secretBinary, "base64");
    writeDump
      ([
        secretBinary,
        hexEncoded,
        base64Encoded,
        binaryDecode(hexEncoded, "hex"),
        binaryDecode(base64Encoded, "base64")
      ]);

    </cfscript>
```